# Approach to parse many zipped xml files with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am completely new to AWS but as I understand it can solve my issue. I have many zipped xml files. And the problem is that both unzipping them and parsing takes forever. From what I read AWS should allow me to do both. But what would be the steps. I understand that I should create lambda functions. So, would it be:

1. Step 1: create lambda function to unzip the files and get my xml files
2. Step 2: create another lambda function to parse the files

Is it correct?

Probably important to say that my zipped files are initially on hard drive. So perhaps I need to upload them to AWS first as well

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not provided enough information for us to advise what is appropriate. What do you want to do with the XML files? Once you have parsed them, what will you be doing with the information? How big are the Zip and XML files (FYI Lambda has a 15-minute execution limit). What have you tried so far (even outside of AWS) and what problems have you experienced? Please Edit your Question to add more information.

Answer (score 1):

What if you used an s3 bucket for the files with an event trigger to call the lambda?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

That way, when you upload a zip file it can call a lambda that will unzip the file and parse it. If you would like multiple steps, you could have the unzip lambda move the unzipped files to a new s3 bucket.

Check out this article;
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/automating-zip-extraction-with-lambda-and-s3-9a083d4e8bab

```
import zipfile
import urllib.parse
from io import BytesIO
from mimetypes import guess_type
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    zip_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])

    try:
        # Get the zipfile from S3
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=zip_key)
        z = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))

        # Extract and upload each file in the zipfile
        for filename in z.namelist():
            content_type = guess_type(filename, strict=False)[0]
            s3.upload_fileobj(
                Fileobj=z.open(filename),
                Bucket=bucket,
                Key=filename,
                ExtraArgs={'ContentType': content_type}
            )
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error getting object {zip_key} from bucket {bucket}.')
        raise e
```

Comment: Yes, it's a good way to respond to every file and upload the unzipped files back to S3. Additional processing could be added to this code to 'process' the XML file. All depends on the actual use-case.